# How to make date as an index in timeseries analysis if I have duplicate dates for each item and store in dataset

Tags: python, time-series, data-science

In timeseries analysis I want to set date as an index but one date has 500 entries 50 for each item and 10 for each store. In such case how can I make date as an index.

Comment: You can't have duplicate values in index...Please provide sample snapshot of your dataframe in your question

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response, I am unable to share snapshot maybe because I am new to stack overflow. But I dealt with this problem by making pivot table and creating multi index data frame. I used both item and datetime as an index

Answer (score 0):

How are you! First off, why do you need de time as index, maybe you can reconsider that idea?
Anyway using datetime should work and the chances to get a duplicate record is minimal

Comment: To perform time series analysis it is often recommended to use date time as an index so that you can check for seasonality, trends , and it overall helps in analysis. But index should always be unique and in my case as I have mentioned, I have 500 entries of one date as for each date, I have data for 50 items and 10 stores so in total 500 entries. 
So now, I created a pivot table and used item and date both as index to deal with this problem

Comment: hi @MaheenUnzeelah, I have same problem can I see your notebook or code